# How to use schema - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, schema

I’m new to the community, I’m also a newbie at php and schema also.

So far I’m building a website for job posting but I would like to display company name with Hiringorganization schema.

Ive already created a taxonomy for companies that has name and description, also thumbnail and website.

The issue here is when I display data on page  and test schema job posting I got the error hiringorganization.

How can I implement the schema to my taxonomy output?

Thanks in advance. I’m using WordPress if that could help as well.

Comment: you can use [plugins like this](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/schema/) to add  structured data markup to your website

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If your question is a coding question, please edit your question to include the *relevant* code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If it isn't about a specific piece of code, then it is outside the scope of this site so one of the other forums might be more suitable.